# How convert string double into numeric double in R?

Tags: r

I have string "178960.02" that should be converted into numeric with floating-point.

This generates only integer value "178960" without ".02".

How to have double value with floating part

```
as.numeric("178960.02")
as.double("178960.02")
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is doing what you want the format for the display is confusing you, try `as.numeric("17.02")` and `as.numeric("178960568675765.02")` and you'll see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
options(digits=9)
as.numeric("178960.02")
```

Output:

```
[1] 178960.02
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine for me. Fixed bug in production.

Comment: There was no bug. Just a difficulty in understanding how R prints values. The decimal fractions persist and would have been carried forward in any calculations.

Comment: @Andrii Fantastic dear colleague! I hope the answer was useful for you!!!

Comment: @Duck Thanks! I even fixed another interesting bug. It's funny but sometimes "==" is not works correctly. For example, ... %>% filter(x1 == x2) %>% ... is not works but ... %>% filter(round(x1, 3) == round(x2, 3)) %>% ... works where "x2" is "178960.02". Thanks for the "options(digits = xxx) tip!

Comment: Done. You can also like me here :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if the questioner was under the impression that the implicit `print` of the R REPL (read-eval-print loop) was actually showing the correct value of a double? (And it appears my worries were well-placed.)

```
x <- as.numeric("178960.02")

 sprintf("%s", x)
#[1] "178960.02"

print(x, digits = 12)
#[1] 178960.02
```

The decimal fraction was always there, just not being displayed. It would not necessarily need to have the global options changed to see the more "complete" value. Other options can be set in `print` arguments.

To see that it was always there it is easy to multiply by 100:

```
x*100
#[1] 17896002
```

Comment: The sprintf("%s", x) generates value of character type (chr "178960.02") when I need numeric value with decimal point for the next numeric calculations

Comment: I understand, and I showed you that the numeric value was always there and how to print it with the decimal factional values. You were only seeing the default behavior of `print` but not understanding that the value was actually there and would have been present in calculations. Try multiplying by 100 and seeing the result.

Comment: Thank you. The question was not about how "to print". It was about how "to have" double value

Comment: It was not a question about "how to print" but it was a perceived (but not real) problem that related to the default behavior of the R `print` function.

Comment: OK. But I can't like your answer as it did not help me here. Maybe someone will find it useful. Thanks for the help!